# How to get alerted if Any AzureDevops Build agent is unavailable?

Tags: azure-devops-extensions, azure-devops-server-2019

How can monitor AzureDevops Build Agent status get alerted for any unexpected behaviour which is not placesd in cloud.

Answer (score 1):

Aftering checking the official [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/notifications/about-notifications?view=azure-devops-2019), there is no built-in notication to monitor the status of agents.

As a workaround, you could monitor the status by checking **"getAgentRequestStatusEndpoint"** frequently using [Rest API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/distributedtask/agentclouds/list?view=azure-devops-server-rest-5.0).

```
GET https://{instance}/{collection}/_apis/distributedtask/agentclouds?api-version=5.0-preview.1
```

Comment: It didnt help me. Tried the url like -"https://xxxxxxxxxxxx.com./devops/myorg/_apis/distributedtask/agentclouds?api-version=5.0-preview.1". But resulted nothing

{"count":0,"value":[]}

Comment: any further update on this?